# Перевод раздела справки "Что такое комментарий?"

Tags: дефект, статус-запланировано, локализация, справка

Русский перевод раздела [help/privileges/comment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) содержит:

> Комментарии - это текущие заметки к вопросу или ответу.

что не достаточно акцентирует временную природу комментариев и важности обновления вопросов и ответов, чтобы сохранить существенную информацию.

Для сравнения [английский аналог](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

*temporary "Post-It" notes* явно указывает на временность комментариев.

> [Comments are second class citizens on the Stack Exchange network, not designed to hold information for all eternity.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/137096)

---

Упомяну здесь так как близко по теме:

Вся информация, необходимая для ответа на вопрос, должна быть в самом вопросе (не в комментариях к вопросу/ответах/файлах на внешних ресурсах итд).

Ответ на вопрос должен быть в самом ответе. Не следует в комментариях на вопрос отвечать.

Мы знаем что иногда люди и отвечают в комментариях и авторы вопросов помещают существенные для ответа детали в комментариях -- в таких случаях можно попросить авторов перенести информацию в ответ/вопрос или сделать это самостоятельно.

- [Is it OK to take someone else's comment and post it as your own answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265676/4279)
- [Is it okay to edit an asker's comment into the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294964/4279)